# Wordpress Custom_post slug и hurl

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming, slug

There is an issue that I cannot solve for a couple of days. All searches come down to the same thing ...

The question is as follows:
 There is a need `to create a new post type` for the convenience of filling the site structure, this is fraught with the fact that a `custom_post_slug` is added to the url, which I want to get rid of.

It is necessary to save the structure of the hurl on the site of the following type:

> site.com/**category**/post_name
> site.com/**category**/category_child/post_name

due to the new post type, whatever one may say, it turns out only like this:

> site.com/**custom_post_slug**/post_name

What I already did:
Most of the recommendations do not solve the problem, for example, `replace slug with '/'` - it will simply remove slug from url.

There is a recommendation when creating a new post type `register_post_type ()` to specify for `rewrite => slug` with the value `%category%`, this resolving my issue but after that all posts of the new post type `get 404`, and I don't understand what to do next.

Add some code:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_addresses() {
    /**
     * Post Type: Addresses.
     */
    $labels = [
        "name" => __( __("Addresses",'cnm_theme'), "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => __( __("Addresses",'cnm_theme'), "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    ];
    $args = [
        "label" => __( __("Addresses",'cnm_theme'), "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ "slug" => '%category%','with_front' => false ],
        // "rewrite" => false,
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => [ "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "trackbacks", "custom-fields", "comments", "revisions", "author", "page-attributes", "post-formats" ],
        "taxonomies" => [ "category", "post_tag" ],
    ];
    register_post_type( "addresses", $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_addresses' );
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your code? It's difficult to debug it without even seeing it!!!!

Comment: @Ruvee here you go

Answer (score 0):

I decide to leave that custom_slug because any changing of url is unwelcome to WP logic, so i leave custom_slug but change it to one letter like:

> site.com**/a/category/category_child/**post_name